# Hide/Unhide a table row with text input depending on the selected dropdown option using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help. If I select Business/Corporate from the dropdown, the table row is visible (which is correct), but when I reselect Residential/Consumer, the row does not hide. All I want is to be able to show the row if Business/Corporate is selected (so that one can enter the business name from the input text field) and hide when not selected. Thanks. :)

My JS:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(target)
     {
         if (target!="") {
         obj=document.getElementById(target);
         obj.style.display=( (obj.style.display=='none') ? '' : 'none');
         }
     }
</script>
```

My select option:

```
<select name="xaccttype" OnChange="toggle(this.value)">
<option value="Residential/Consumer">Residential/Consumer
<option value="Business/Corporate">Business/Corporate
</select>
```

My table row:

```
<tr id="Business/Corporate" style="display:none"><td width="200" align="right"><b>Business Name:</b></td><td width="650"><input type="text" size="35" name="xbusinessname"></td></tr>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/yw6v4x71/

Comment: Do not use `/` for `id`. Use `_` or `-` instead

Comment: Hi Sandeep. I tried your script from jsfiddle and works perfect. But when I copied it into my site, it's giving a warning saying that console is undefined.

Comment: I believe you are using Internet Explorer..in that case just keep your developer tools open and run. (i.e Hit F12. and then run)

Comment: Or place this script `<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>` at the top of your page..in head section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give some different `id` to the `tr`. Then do the following in the script. Make sure you do not use `/` for `id` names.

Since, you do not have other row with the `id` as `Residential_Consumer`, it would not be feasible to check the target dynamically in the script.

```js
function toggle(target)
     {
         console.log("inside");
         console.log(target);
         if (target!="") {
         obj=document.getElementById("row");
             console.log(obj);
           if(target === "Business_Corporate")
                obj.style.display= 'block';
           else
              obj.style.display= 'none';
         }
     }
```

```html
<select name="xaccttype" OnChange="toggle(this.value)">
<option value="Residential_Consumer">Residential/Consumer</option>
<option value="Business_Corporate">Business/Corporate</option>
</select>
   <table> 
    <tr id="row" style="display:none">
        <td width="200" align="right"><b>Business Name:</b></td>
        <td width="650"><input type="text" size="35" name="xbusinessname"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Thank you much Sandeep!!! Yes, I'm using IE and copied your script and is now working. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: It is a problem only in IE. Other browsers should work well without it. Glad to be of help. You are welcome!

Comment: Sandeep, I tried running it on Chrome and the row went to the left most position of the site. Do you have a fix for this? Thanks again. :)

Comment: To do with the CSS. You will have to check it though.